# Augmented reality to detect hand heart with webcam

Tags: flash, webcam, augmented-reality

Is it possible?

I'm studying and I'd like tips and links to tutorials that can help me.

[image: Augmented Reality]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a similar program using haarcascades with opencv. I'm sure it could easily tied into ARToolKit. Check out my tutorial.
http://danielscvtutorials.blogspot.com/p/impress-that-special-someone-with.html

I was able to tie ARToolKit to OpenCv with this code. For some reason ARToolKit wanted to use ARGB instead of BGR or RGBA.

```
ARUint8 rgbTmp[3];
for(int y=0; y < image_opencv->height; y++) {
    for(int x=0; x < image_opencv->width; x++) {
        rgbTmp[0] = image_opencv->imageData[image_opencv->widthStep * y + x*3]; // B
        rgbTmp[1] = image_opencv->imageData[image_opencv->widthStep * y + x*3 + 1]; // G
        rgbTmp[2] = image_opencv->imageData[image_opencv->widthStep * y + x*3 + 2]; // R
        frame->imageData[frame->widthStep * y + x*4] = 255; // A
        frame->imageData[frame->widthStep * y + x*4 + 1] = rgbTmp[2]; // R
        frame->imageData[frame->widthStep * y + x*4 + 2] = rgbTmp[1]; // G
        frame->imageData[frame->widthStep * y + x*4 + 3] = rgbTmp[0]; // B
    }
}
ARUint8 *arImage = (ARUint8 *)frame->imageData; // This is very fast conversion
```

Answer (score 1):

A really simple example can be found here (in flash though):
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/augmented_reality.html

it uses papervision, flar and flex sdk to do what you need.
If you are familiar with actionscript you can have it up and running with your
own images and models in a couple of hours (changing the pattern that needs to be detected cost me about 10 mins to figure out how)

This example uses pattern recognition on black and white images so it should be able to recognize shapes also.

There is a tool bundled with it that can create a pattern file from an image,
all you need to do is cut the heart shape out of your posted image,
convert it to black / white and make a pattern.

Since your webcam creates color video you may need to convert this to greyscale
in order to work.

I think it mostly takes a lot of tweaking to get it to work, but it shouldn't be impossible

Comment: My difficulty is identifying the format of the hand instead of a paper. It should not be easy, but I'll try... Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with the FLARToolKit, or Flash Augmented Reality Toolkit.

http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en

Adobe teamed with John Mayer on a project, which can be seen at this YouTube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZtRHVMcZjI

...or print the icon and demo live with a web cam at:

http://www.johnmayer.com/ar/